# ¿Cómo evitar colocar comas en un textarea y que las mismas se coloquen automáticamente al pulsar enter?

Tags: javascript

Lo que quiero evitar es que se inserten comas desde el teclado, puesto que éstas ya se insertan automáticamente al pulsar "enter".

```js
const input = document.getElementById('coma');

input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        input.value += ', ';
    }
});
```

```html
 <textarea type="text" name="post_tags" class="form-control" placeholder="Agregar" value="" id="coma"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que detener el comportamiento default del evento cuando detectes que se ha pulsado la tecla de coma.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('coma');

input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 188) { // 188 es el keyCode de la tecla coma.
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        input.value += ', ';
    }
});
```

```html
 <textarea type="text" name="post_tags" class="form-control" placeholder="Agregar" value="" id="coma"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisa cuando se pulsa una coma

```js
const input = document.getElementById('coma');

    input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            input.value += ', ';
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 188) { //Coma
            e.preventDefault();
            input.value +=' ';//Sustituir por un espacio, por ejemplo
        }
    });
```

```html
<textarea type="text" name="post_tags" class="form-control" placeholder="Agregar" value="" id="coma"></textarea>
```