# ¿Cómo prevenir el uso de la coma en un input y que ésta se coloque en forma automática al presionar enter con php y js?

Tags: javascript, php

Estuve intentando pero como no tengo mucha experiencia no sé en que me estoy equivocando.

Disculpen Uds no tengo mucha experiencia, estoy intentando que cuando se presione la tecla **enter** se coloque una **coma automáticamente**, y si se presiona la tecla **"coma, punto y coma, y tab"** no lo permita y quede prohibido, sólamente si se da enter.

```
<?php $variable = "naranja,banana"; ?> 
<input type="text" id="bloquear" name="post_tags" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Agregar" value="<?php echo esc_html($variable);?>">

 <script>
const input = document.getElementById('bloquear');
input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
if (e.keyCode == 188) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
if (e.keyCode == 16) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    input.value += ', ';
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ya tienes [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/463873/54039) con el mismo tema (al menos muy parecido) y con respuesta aceptada. ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema? Al tratarse de un `input` y no `textarea`, el comportamiento normal de la tecla Enter es procesar un formulario y, tal vez, solo necesitas incluir `e.preventDefault();` para que funcione como esperas.

Comment: no entiendo, qué se supone que está fallando?

Comment: creo que tu comentario está fuera de lugar, el hecho de que pases un `value` a tu `input` no afecta en **NADA** al comportamiento de tu script; vuelvo a preguntar, **¿qué se supone que está fallando?**

Comment: Te recomiendo que releas el [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct). Este tipo de comentarios pueden llevar a la suspensión de tu cuenta. Ya han sido reportados.

Comment: citando al [tour], Este sitio es para obtener respuestas. **No es un foro** de discusión. No es un lugar de conversación. Segundo, puedes preguntar las veces que quieras, pero si tu pregunta es igual a algo ya existente en el sitio, suele marcarse como duplicado y no suelen responderse ese tipo de preguntas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo evitar colocar comas en un textarea y que las mismas se coloquen automáticamente al pulsar enter?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463873/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-colocar-comas-en-un-textarea-y-que-las-mismas-se-coloquen-autom%c3%a1tic)